# Issue with PEM file while building a query using Laravel and Goutte

Tags: laravel, goutte

I'm building a website using Laravel 8 and Goutte 4. I'm trying to send a request to a website that requires authentication with a .pem file. In order to do so, I include the 'local_cert' param when creating the instance of http-client like this:

```php
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

class Query
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = (new Client(
            HttpClient::create([
                'timeout'    => 30,
                'local_cert' => //absolute path to the .pem file,
            ])
        ));
    }
    public function query() {
        $this->client->request('GET', "https://palena.sii.cl/cvc_cgi/dte/of_solicita_folios");
    }
}
```

This works perfectly well on my local server, but when I try it on the production server, I get an Exception: "Problem with the local SSL certificate". The .pem file being used is the same in development and production, and the php can read the file in the production server.

The full error in the laravel Log is:

> [2020-12-02 21:32:30] production.ERROR: Problem with the local SSL certificate for "https://palena.sii.cl/cvc_cgi/dte/of_solicita_folios". {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\TransportException(code: 0): Problem with the local SSL certificate for "https://palena.sii.cl/cvc_cgi/dte/of_solicita_folios". at /my/path/vendor/symfony/http-client/Chunk/ErrorChunk.php:65)

Comment: Are you certain the certificate is valid in your production environment? No line-ending problems?

Comment: I am. Is the exact same one.

Answer (score 0):

did you fixed? i only make this work with GuzzleHttp

```
$requestAuthentication = $clientAuth->request('GET', $urlAuthentication, [
        'cert' => [$rutaPem, 'clave'],
        'cookies' => $cookiesAuth,
    ]);
```